# Grid view Link button not firing on click asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

Grid view Link button (one of the column) onclick not firing. Really unable to understand what am doing wrong. need help. rookie in coding.

**.aspx**

```
     <asp:GridView ID="gridTSRJOBList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable print-first-column-hide" CellSpacing="0" Width="100%"  ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No TSR JOB Found for this Lease" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="JobID"role="grid">                       
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkJobID" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("JobID") %>' Text='<%#Eval("JobID") %>'  OnClick="lnkJobID_Click"></asp:LinkButton></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="Category" ReadOnly="True"  />
<asp:BoundField DataField="JobDetail" HeaderText="Short Description" ReadOnly="True" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="JobType" HeaderText="Job Status" ReadOnly="True" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerReference" HeaderText=" Customer Reference" ReadOnly="True" />
 </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

**C# code**

```
protected void lnkJobID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        LinkButton jobLinkbutton = new LinkButton();
        jobLinkbutton = (LinkButton)sender;
        Response.Redirect("TSR_proc.aspx?bl=1&JOBID=" + jobLinkbutton.CommandArgument);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using updatepanel in your page?

Comment: @Koderzzzz no mate

Comment: user causesvalidation="false" in the link button

Comment: not worked @Koderzzzz

Comment: Tested your code, it works fine. The problem is not in the code you posted.

Comment: @VDWWD then what's the problem?

Comment: I dont know. Its not in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

take off `lnkJobID_Click` from linkbutton and add `CommandName='clickLink'`.
You can manage this event inside the Gridview RowCommand Event, in your case

```
gridTSRJOBList_RowCommand
```